# how to pass data from notification to activity in android

Tags: android-notifications

i need to create two statusbar Notifications.when i click first notification icon., i've to disaply some data(ex.activity1).,if i click second notification icon.,i've to display another data(Ex.activity2).i've created well.But i couldnt able to display data.

My code:

```
package com.collabera.labs.sai;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SimpleNotification extends Activity {

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID_A = 0;
    private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID_B = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notifyButton);        
        //Button cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // display A
                displayNotification("Extra for A", "This is A", "Some text for activity A", MyActivityA.class, SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID_A);
                // display B
                displayNotification("Extra for B", "This is B", "Some text for activity B", MyActivityB.class, SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID_B);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayNotification(String extra, String contentTitle, String contentText, Class<?> cls, int id) {     
        Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "New Alert!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putString("extra", extra);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(id, notifyDetails);

}

}
```

On MyActivityA:

```
TextView tv;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sub);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    String value = b.getString("extra");
    tv.setText(value);
```

Whats error on this..It didnt displayed the text..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
First activity:

```
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis(); Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class); intent.putExtra("data1", "My Data 1"); intent.putExtra("data2", "My Data 2"); PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, intent, 0);
```

Second activity that called from First activity

PUT this in oncreated method

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){
    String data1 = extras.getString("data1");
    String data2 = extras.getString("data2");
    Log.e("Ddata1" + data1, data2);
}
```